# Delete matrix rows based on a threshold coverage with another matrix in r

Tags: r

I have a `matrix` composed of sites and species. Some species have a certain trait value but not all of them.
I want to keep only the site-species `matrix` rows that contain enough trait information, in my case more than 60%.

So far, I have the following `for-loop` but I would like to have a faster version of this code. How can I optimize this and skip the `for-loop` part?

```
# site-species matrix
A <- matrix(c(0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.4), byrow = T, nrow = 2)
colnames(A) <- paste0("sp_", seq(ncol(A)))
rownames(A) <- paste0("site_", seq(nrow(A)))
# trait information
B <- data.frame(sp = paste0("sp_", seq(1:ncol(A))),
                value = c(NA, NA, 2, 3))
# For-loop to get the coverage percentage for each row
pcover <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  non_null_A <- A[i, ][A[i, ] > 0]
  B_match <- match(names(non_null_A), B[, "sp"])
  B_value <- B[B_match, "value"]
  pcover <- rbind(pcover,
                  sum(!is.na(B_value)) / length(B_value) * 100)
}
A
A[pcover > 60, , drop = FALSE] # in this case, the second site is removed
```

Comment: instead of `length(B_value[!is.na(B_value)])` you could write `sum(!is_na(B_value))`

Comment: `seq(1:ncol(A))` makes no sense. Either `seq(ncol(A))` or `1:ncol(A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you have two conditions working together:

- is `A` positive ?
- is `B$value` `NA` ?

We compute these tests from the start and use only vectorized code :

```
Apos <- A[,B$sp] > 0 # or just A>0 here but I assumed from your code that you'd needed this
pcover <- 100* colSums(t(Apos) & !is.na(B$value)) /rowSums(Apos) 
pcover
# site_1   site_2 
# 66.66667 33.33333

A[pcover > 60, , drop = FALSE] 
#        sp_1 sp_2 sp_3 sp_4
# site_1    0  0.2  0.2  0.6
```

Comment: Great, I was looking for a vectorized answer. Thank you.